# Why do table cells increase when I increase the padding?

Tags: css

I'm using this css code to style my table cells.

```
td{
    padding: .2vw;
    width: 8vw;
    height: 8vw;
}
```

When I increase the padding my cells get wider. Why is this? I thought the width does already include the padding. How can I set the actual width of my cells?

**Edit:** Here is a complete example:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
<style>
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
table{
    font-size: 1em;
    border-spacing: 0.7vw;
    background-color: #003d1b;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
td{
    background-color: #00551b;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 1vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8vw;
    height: 8vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not it doesn't include the padding. Try setting box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: Try to "box-sizing: border-box;"

Comment: Doesn't change anything :(

Comment: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table> try using this.

Comment: @nazifarashid Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

add box-sizing:border-box; in to td

```
td{
    padding: .2vw;
    width: 8vw;
    height: 8vw;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: can you please share the demo ?

Comment: I added a working example to my question. The cells should be squares but they are wider. In every browser I've tried (Firefox & Chrome).

Comment: you added box-sizing: border-box; to the table. you have to add it in td.

Comment: I added it to td as well. Didn't change anything. In my example it is in the table because is was there even before I started my question here.

Comment: Actually it is working fine for me. can you please create fiddle so I can get better idea.

Comment: The problem is that in fiddle it works fine for me as well. Try to create an html file with my code. Then it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to do so and experienced the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "width: 100%" or fixed-width (500px) on the table...

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%
}
```

And if you did not want to increase the height when you gave padding also then use 'box-sizing:border-box;' in td

```
td{
    padding: 1.2vw;
    width: 8vw;
    height: 8vw;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: "width: 100%" streches my table to the full screen width. That's not what I want. I want each cell to have width 8vw.

Comment: You can add a fixed width ion table in **px**, how much you want to do increase width Ex. max-width: 300px;